# Using open source while writing a library in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to find more information / explanation for the following scenario:

I'm writing a library in Swift and would like to use some open source library in it. 
If I just integrate them into my library, is there a chance of namespace collision?
What would happen if the host app will use:

- The exact same open source library
- The same library but different version

Does using CocoaPods changes something here?
Consider a scenario where I import AFNetworking for example (via CocoaPods) in my library, and the host app will use it too.

Comment: Modules act as namespaces. If two modules have the same name, it's going to cause an issue. Simple answer: don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same library, you won't have any issues. Using different version will likely cause problems, but that is going to be dependent on the changes made in the different versions.

Namespace collisions in Swift are rare. As @mattt stated, each module acts as a namespace, so naming conflicts with classes or functions from another module won't exist as they do in Objective-C. If you have a naming conflict, the compiler will tell you. In that case, you can just prefix the conflicting signature with the module name.

I would highly recommend you use [Cocoapods](http://www.cocoapods.org) for dependency management. It handles version control and will make your life much easier.